# Mongoose get and set not working on Array Fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection where I have to store array of userNames which needs to be encrypted(Don't ask why!).

```
const UserNameSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    // Other Fields...
    // ...
    "userNames": {
        type: Array,
        set: encryptUserDetails,
        get: decryptUserDetails
    },
}, {
    toObject: { getters: true, setters: true },
    toJSON: { getters: true, setters: true },
    runSettersOnQuery: true
});
```

But when I try to write any data into it, it is not calling the set method.

Here is how I am trying to write data in to the DB.

```
 let addUserNameResult = await UserNameModel.update({// find condition omitted},
                {
                    $addToSet: {
                        "userNames": "new_user_name"
                    }
                }, {
                upsert: true,
                new: true
            });
```

But this Query still stores the data in plain text without calling my set method.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Edit: encryptUserDetails method added.

```js
let encryptUserDetails = (plainText) => {
     // Some encryption algorithm ... (No issues here, It works).
     // . . .
     return encryptedText;
}
```

Comment: add `encryptUserDetails` function to the question

Comment: Sure, added the blueprint of the method above. The method itself is working fine with other fields in the DB.

Comment: the encryptUserDetails has not await function???

Comment: No, It does not have any await.